# How to switch device language directly from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, localization

Xcode has the ability to directly switch the device language.
**Can I do something similar in Android Studio?**

[image]

Comment: I think that you can only change it within the emulator itself as you would on a real device. I don't think there's a quick setting for that, at least not in AS 2.5.2

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I think so too, but I decided to clarify

Comment: Android studio has no such tools. But you likely can change it using ADB command